# change value dispayed with onValueSelected - MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I show percentage values in my pieChart. I want to change those values to real amounts when the user clicks on the slice. Is that possible by using onValueSelected()? I don't want to use IMarker as it's a bit complicated for me. I tried doing this but it didn't work:

```
override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {
    val amount = (e as PieEntry).value
    e.y = amount 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting a unique index attribute for each `PieEntry`, using a `OnChartValueSelectedListener` to keep track of which item is selected, and a `ValueFormatter` to choose how to render the item's value text based on whether it is the selected item or not.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val chart = findViewById<PieChart>(R.id.chart)

    val myData = listOf(10f,20f,50f)

    // Step 1: Create a list of PieEntry objects that uses
    // the source data index as its "data" attribute
    val entries = myData.mapIndexed { i, v -> PieEntry(v, i)}

    val dataset = PieDataSet(entries, "Values")

    dataset.isHighlightEnabled = true
    dataset.valueTextSize = 14f
    dataset.colors = listOf(
        Color.parseColor("#FF32DA64"),
        Color.parseColor("#FF32DAD4"),
        Color.parseColor("#FFB853F2")
    )

    // Step 2: Create a value formatter that compares the pie entry data
    // (aka index in the original list) with the selected index to choose
    // what value to show
    val myValueFormatter = object : ValueFormatter() {
        override fun getPieLabel(value: Float, pieEntry: PieEntry?): String {
            val idx = pieEntry?.data as? Int ?: -2
            return if (idx == selectedIndex ) {
                // Show the value for the selected item
                "$value"
            }
            else {
                // Show percentage for all the rest
                "${value / myData.sum() * 100f} %"
            }
        }
    }

    dataset.valueFormatter = myValueFormatter

    // Step 3: Add a value selected listener to change the selected index
    chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(object : OnChartValueSelectedListener {
        override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {
            selectedIndex = h?.x?.roundToInt() ?: -1
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected() {
            selectedIndex = -1
        }

    })

    chart.data = PieData(dataset)
    chart.description.isEnabled = false
    chart.legend.isEnabled = false
}
```

Which looks like (de-selected on the left, selected on the right):

[image: pie demo]